# Compare each list's element with others in the list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

So, there is a list like

```
list=["one","two","ne","three"....]
```

I wonder, how do I compare each element of the list with others by using endswith() method?
in this list, for example, list[0] endwith list[2].

I couldn't get how to make a comparison itself.
I'm trying something like:

```
aa=list
flg=False
for i in range(len(ll)-1):
    aa.append(ll[i+1])
    if ll[i].endswith(aa[i]):
        flg=True
```

however, it's good only for the first element, not with each one.

Comment: How does `list[2] contain list[3]`?

Comment: sorry, list[0] contain list[2]

Comment: How does `list[0] contain list[3]`? Also, what's is `ll`?

Comment: list[0] contain list[2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sets:

```
words = {"one","two","ne","three"}

[x for x in words if any(word.endswith(x) for word in words - {x})]
Out[69]: ['ne']
```

Basically, for each element, remove it from the `words` set, and then test if any of the other words in the truncated set end with that word.

Comment: okay, seems very nice, thx, 'll check sets in pytho on the internet

Answer (score 1):

You are only doing a single pass through the list, even though you have stated your goal as "*Compare each element of the list with the others*". This necessitates making one traversal of the list *per element in the list*. If you have n items, you will traverse the list n times for every item, for a total of n^2 traversals.

Hence, you need **two** for loops in your solution: one to traverse the list once and select the element that will be compared, and inside that loop, another that will check that element against the others.

```
for n in ll:
    for m in ll:
        if m.endswith(n) and m != n:
            print(m, "ends with", n)
```